# finding an amount of variable in a text file by python

Tags: python, variables, text

I have a variable which its amount is changing every time. I like to know how can I find the line which contained the amount of my variable.
I am looking something like this:
but in this way it looks for the letter of "A"
how can I write a command which look for its amount("100")?
I tried this before

```
A = 100
with open ('my_file') as f:
    for line in f :
        if "A" in line:
           print line
```

Comment: 1. `A = "100"`. 2. `if A in line:`.

Comment: If you want to use the value of the variable, don't put it in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting quotes around something makes it a String. You want to actually reference the variable which contains your number, i.e. `A` instead of `"A"`

```
A = 100
with open('my_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        # str() converts an integer into a string for searching.
        if str(A) in line:
            print line
```